# Spring Autowiring not working for RabbitListenerContainer

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring AMQP's MessageListenerContainer for recieving messages from RabbitMq Broker . Though I am able to receive message inside the listener , autowiring is not working inside listener .

Here is how I have configured my Listener

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(this.inputQueueMgr
            .getRabbitConnectionFactory());
    JsonMessageConverter converter = new JsonMessageConverter();
    listenerContainer.setMessageConverter(converter);
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener(new InputQueueEventDispatcher());
    listenerContainer.setQueueNames("queue1");
    listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    listenerContainer.setPrefetchCount(1);
    return listenerContainer;
}
```

Here is the class where I am listening to the messages from rabbitMq

```
@Component(value = "inputMessageListner")
public class InputQueueEventDispatcher implements Serializable, MessageListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5391659256992655430L;

@Autowired
private volatile InputQueueManagerImpl inputQueueMgr;

@Autowired
private volatile NotificationQueueManagerImpl notificationManager;

@Value("${input.rabbitmq.events.queue}")
private String queueName;

@Autowired
private SubscriptionRepository subRepository;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        String messageContent = new String(message.getBody());
         .....
 }
```

The problem is inside onMessage(Message message) all the autowire components are coming as null .

PS-> Please note that I have declared all the autowire instances as @Component and doing appropriate ComponentScan to scan their packages appropriately . Infact these components do get autowired in normal flow but since onMessage(Message message) gets executed on a seperate thread , these values are showing null . Is there any way to enable autowiring here inside listener .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You've set a @Component annotation on your listener, but you don't get this bean from the context. Instead, you're creating the instance yourself, using `new`. So Spring has no way to know that this instance has been created and must be autowired.

Remove that `@Component` annotation, and change your code to

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(this.inputQueueMgr
            .getRabbitConnectionFactory());
    JsonMessageConverter converter = new JsonMessageConverter();
    listenerContainer.setMessageConverter(converter);
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener(inputMessageListener());
    listenerContainer.setQueueNames("queue1");
    listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    listenerContainer.setPrefetchCount(1);
    return listenerContainer;
}

@Bean 
public InputQueueEventDispatcher inputMessageListener() {
    return new InputQueueEventDispatcher();
}
```

Now, since the bean is returned from a `@Bean`-annotated method, Spring will make is a Spring bean and autowire it.

Comment: Have already tried this ..But this still doesnt work(tried it again as well with ur comment) . To put it differently , I am getting Autowiring enabled when the InputQueueEventDispatcher is being initialized the first time (due to @Component but the onMessage(..) method is being invoked on a seperate TaskExecutor Thread . There I am losing all the dependencies autowired

Answer (score -1):

Most probably the other thread you mentioned on your question is not getting that instance from spring's application context. So no injection happens for it.

You should use

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queue_name")
```

on your onMessage method.
But you should also change onMessage method syntax and and

```
onMessage(Message<String> originalMessage)
```

that way spring will automatically call that method with message

Comment: So , how to make this thread get Spring's ApplicationContext?

Comment: my method onMessage does get called (on a seperate thread) but the problem  is I see all dependencies autowired as null :(